# How to disable SSR for certain pages in Nuxt3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm developing an application in Nuxt 3. Part of that application is only accessible if you are logged in. I want to disable SSR for those routes, while keeping it on for routes that are publicly available.

Is there a way to do that in Nuxt 3? I only found an option to disable SSR globally in the `nuxt.config.ts` file

Comment: This question should be reopened. The linked question solves it only for Nuxt2.

Comment: @manniL, the other _question_ does not specifically ask about Nuxt 2. Are you talking about a particular answer? Do the answers for Nuxt >v2.9.0 apply to Nuxt 3 (I honestly don't know)? In any case, this question remains a duplicate of the other one and should remain closed.

Comment: @Chris Sadly, the given answer is not valid for Nuxt 3, only Nuxt 2.
Because handling this is way different for Nuxt 3 and Nuxt 2, I don't necessarily see it as duplicate, as the other question is rather considering Nuxt 2 only (given the date of creation and answers. It makes sense to have different answers for each version IMO.

Comment: @manniL, we don't decide whether questions are duplicates based on the answers they have received, but based on what they _ask_. Since the older question doesn't specificy Nuxt 2, I'd argue that this question remains a duplicate. An answer for Nuxt 3 could be properly added to the older question. If you have such an answer, I'd encourage you to add it over there. If not, a bounty can be added the older question to encourage other users to add new answers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is [Hybrid rendering](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#hybrid-rendering) in which you can specify some parameters for each page, `ssr` included:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routeRules: {
    // Homepage pre-rendered at build time
    '/': { prerender: true },
    // Product page generated on-demand, revalidates in background
    '/products/**': { swr: 3600 },
    // Blog post generated on-demand once until next deploy
    '/blog/**': { isr: true },
    // Admin dashboard renders only on client-side
    '/admin/**': { ssr: false },
  }
})
```